# Fitting a conformal / holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

Suppose we have some 2D points $x_i$ (which we may take to be complex numbers) and some corresponding 2D points $y_i$. We seek a function $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(x_i)\approx y_i$, and $f$ has to be conformal / holomorphic.

(it suffices that $f$ is conformal in the convex hull of the $x_i$, it doesn't have to be conformal everywhere)

Now there is a straightforward way of doing this: just use the [Lagrange polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial). A polynomial can be constructed for which all $f(x_i)=y_i$, and, being polynomial, it is also holomorphic and thus conformal. Problem solved, right?

The [disadvantages of the Lagrange polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%27s_phenomenon) are well known, and lead me to suspect that this is not actually a good solution. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use Spline functions. Depending of your data, it can be done in 2D [1](https://hephaistos.lpp.polytechnique.fr/rhodecode/GIT_REPOSITORIES/LPP/Users/Lucken/bernard).
The `scipy` function proposes a numerical implementation [here](https://scipython.com/book/chapter-8-scipy/examples/two-dimensional-interpolation-with-scipyinterpolaterectbivariatespline/) if the data is know on a cartesian mesh.

If you know that your data has a compact support, or more precisely if is as:
$$ \lim_{|z| \rightarrow + \infty} \exp(z^2) f(z) = 0,$$
then you could use the Hermite transform.
This is quite tractable in 2D [2](https://scipython.com/book/chapter-8-scipy/examples/two-dimensional-interpolation-with-scipyinterpolaterectbivariatespline/). 
This python module is doing it: [Bernard](https://hephaistos.lpp.polytechnique.fr/rhodecode/GIT_REPOSITORIES/LPP/Users/Lucken/bernard)

[1](https://hephaistos.lpp.polytechnique.fr/rhodecode/GIT_REPOSITORIES/LPP/Users/Lucken/bernard) Opfer, G., Puri, M.L., 1981. Complex planar splines. Journal of Approximation Theory 31, 383–402. https://doi.org/10.1016/0021-9045(81)90104-0

[2](https://scipython.com/book/chapter-8-scipy/examples/two-dimensional-interpolation-with-scipyinterpolaterectbivariatespline/) Wünsche, A. (2001) Hermite and Laguerre 2D Polynomials. Journal of Computational and Applied Mathematics, 133, 665-678.
http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/s0377-0427(00)00681-6